# AppCenter: How to retrieve the `name` property of `notification_content` object in Xamarin?

Tags: android, xamarin, push-notification, visual-studio-app-center

I'm looking at the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/appcenter/push/rest-api) on sending push notifications using AppCenter. I was able to successfully create and send push notifications, but I can't understand why we need the `name` property in the `notification_content` object. Is it required? Who uses it?

The reason I ask is I want to filter out notifications on the client device based on their type. I was hoping to use the `name` property for this purpose instead of creating another property in the `custom_data`.

On Android, I could retrieve notification title and text like so:

```
var title = statusBarNotification.Notification.Extras.GetString("android.title");
var text = statusBarNotification.Notification.Extras.GetString("android.text");
```

Is there a way to retrieve the `name` property as well?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**First** there is no way to receive `name` property from Notification , you can not retrieve it from data of notification as follow image .

[image]

**Second** this property is only used for **App Center** to display in notification list ,and not finding way to retrieve it from App Center .

From [Send Notification document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/appcenter/push/rest-api#sending-notifications) , `name` property is used to define the name for the notification message as follow .

```
{
  "notification_content": {
    "name": "First Push From App Center",
    "title": "Push From App Center",
    "body": "Hello! Isn't this an amazing notification message?",
    "custom_data": {"key1": "val1", "key2": "val2"}
  }
}
```

- `name`: Defines the name for the notification message.

If you have a look a [this document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/appcenter/push/send-notification#compose) about send notification without using API in App Center , you will see **Campaign Name** is the `name` property in API .

> Populate the **Campaign Name** field with a descriptive name for the campaign. The value you provide will display in the App Center campaign list page.

It just display in App Center list page , however I also can not find other api to get this property in App Center .

**Therefore** , if we can not retrieve it from Notification Data or even from App Center , then I will suggest you to use **custom_data** to custom your needed data .

Comment: Thanks. I too thought `name` was being used by AppCenter, but the documentation did not make it clear.

Comment: @user246392 Yeah , that's right . The doc of api not explaining more about it . We just can know it from [doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/appcenter/push/send-notification#compose) of url in App Center .